# Duplicate entry MySQL while check before

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, I check if ip exists in database first before insert but still gives me duplicate entry sometimes, how is possible?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip=?"; // SQL with parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bind_param("s",$ip);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
if($result->num_rows>0){

}else{

$sql = "INSERT INTO table 
    (*)
    VALUES
    (*)"; // SQL with parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bind_param("*",*);
$stmt->execute();


}
```

Does someone knows why still gives duplicate entry sometimes?
Regards,

Comment: Are there other sessions inserting at the same time? There is a brief time between the SELECT and the INSERT when a concurrent session could slip in and insert that address. This is called a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). You might think the chances of this happening are remote, but obviously it does.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a race condition problem. If you have two threads running the same script, it could be that the first query will return nothing, then one of the threads will do the insert and the other one will try to make another insert causing the duplicate entry issue. Maybe you could solve that with a try catch block